# How to make the box page number is in line?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor,lipsum}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\colorlet{myfancycolor}{black}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \renewcommand*\footrulewidth{1pt}
    \fancyfoot[OR]{%
        \color{myfancycolor}\rule{2em}{2em}\raisebox{0.5em}{\hspace{-2em}\color{white}\makebox[2em][c]{\textsf{\thepage}}}%
        \vspace*{-0.8em}%
    }
    \fancyfoot[OL]{%
        \leftmark
    }    
    \fancyfoot[EL]{%
        \color{myfancycolor}\rule{2em}{2em}\raisebox{0.5em}{\hspace{-2em}\color{white}\makebox[2em][c]{\textsf{\thepage}}}%
        \vspace*{-0.8em}%
    } 
    \fancyfoot[ER]{%
        \rightmark
    }
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \chapter{PREFACE}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{LALALA}
    \lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want the box page number is in line as follows:

[image]

I have tried to change the value of `\raisebox` to -1 em, -2 em and it cannot change the layout.

How to make the box page number is in line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `\renewcommand\footrulewidth{1pt}` and create your own `\hrule` (i.e. no `\hrule` generated by used package). Your `\hrule` can be immediately followed by `\hbox`, so there is no space between `\hrule` and `\hbox`. For example, it can look like this:

```
\fancyfoot[EL]{%
    \kern-3ex % all material is shifted up by 3ex
    \color{myfancycolor}
    \hrule height1pt % your \hrule
    \hbox{\rlap{\vrule height1.3em width2em depth.7em}% you black box
          \hbox to2em{\hss\color{white}{\textsf{\thepage}}\hss}}%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the whole thing in another `\raisebox`:

```
\raisebox{4pt}[2em]{\color{myfancycolor}\rule{2em}{2em}\raisebox{0.5em}{\hspace{-2em}\color{white}\makebox[2em][c]{\textsf{\thepage}}}%
        \vspace*{-0.8em}}
```